# Adding a variable to a Vertical Panel in GAS

Tags: user-interface, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a master sheet which *should* have a UiApp embedded into the active sheet. I have tried coding the first part with the labels in the first row, but I am stuck with getting the names[i] to appear on the left hand side of the table under the Tasks label.

I intend to make check boxes appear for every name under each task label.

Here is the code below:

```
function showTable() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var TL = ss.getRange('B3').getValue();
//SetFontWeight("bold") for TL < *This does not work either* >

var startDate = ss.getRange('B2').getValue();
var strStartDate = startDate.getDate() + "/" + (startDate.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + StartDate.getFullYear();

var counta = ss.getRange('B4').getValue();

var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(375).setWidth(620)
.setTitle('This is ' + TL + "'s Team Tasks for " + strStartDate);

var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setId('panel').setHeight(355).setWidth(605)
.setStyleAttribute('background', 'lightCyan');

var names = ss.getRange('B11:B').getValues();

for (var i = 0; 0 < names.length; i++)   **//This is the part that does not work**
{
 var agents = app.createLabel(names[i]); 
}

var handler1 = app.createServerHandler('btnCloseWindow'); 
var btnCloseWindow = app.createButton('Close Window').addClickHandler(handler1).setStyleAttribute('background', 'lightYellow');
handler1.addCallbackElement(panel);

var myLabel0 = app.createLabel('Tasks');
var myLabel1 = app.createLabel('HW');
var myLabel2 = app.createLabel('MU');
var myLabel3 = app.createLabel('MOV');

panel.add(myLabel0, 40, 12)
panel.add(myLabel1, 100, 12)
panel.add(myLabel2, 140, 12)
panel.add(myLabel3, 175, 12)

panel.add(agents, 40, 30)

panel.add(btnCloseWindow, 490, 320)
app.add(panel);
ss.show(app);
return app;
};

function btnCloseWindow(e) 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
app.close();
return app;
};
```

How do you make a vertical panel with the names?
The names are defined in col B11:B and the tasks are defined in the labels.

This is my first time making a UiApp so any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Is `agents` supposed to be an array of labels? Right now, each iteration of the names loop is overwriting the variable. You could loop through each label in `agents` and add it to the panel at `40 + 40 * i` to add names every 40 pixels.

Comment: Frederic is right, or you can add agent to app in your loop directly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it like this, I don't know how the whole think should look like but the part with the list of names is now right...

```
function showTable() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var TL = ss.getRange('B3').getValue()  
ss.getRange('B3').setFontWeight('bold')
var startDate = ss.getRange('B2').getValue();
var strStartDate = Utilities.formatDate(startDate, ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), 'dd/mm/yyyy');

var counta = ss.getRange('B4').getValue();

var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(375).setWidth(620)
.setTitle('This is ' + TL + "'s Team Tasks for " + strStartDate);

var panel = app.createAbsolutePanel().setId('panel').setHeight(355).setWidth(605)
.setStyleAttribute('background', 'lightCyan');

var handler1 = app.createServerHandler('btnCloseWindow'); 
var btnCloseWindow = app.createButton('Close Window').addClickHandler(handler1).setStyleAttribute('background', 'lightYellow');
handler1.addCallbackElement(panel);

var myLabel0 = app.createLabel('Tasks');
var myLabel1 = app.createLabel('HW');
var myLabel2 = app.createLabel('MU');
var myLabel3 = app.createLabel('MOV');

panel.add(myLabel0, 40, 12)
panel.add(myLabel1, 100, 12)
panel.add(myLabel2, 140, 12)
panel.add(myLabel3, 175, 12)

var names = ss.getRange('B11:B').getValues();
Logger.log(names)
for(i=0;i<names.length;++i){
Logger.log(names[i][0]);// names is a 2D array, you only want the first and only column
if(names[i][0]!=''){ // don't show if empty
panel.add(app.createLabel(names[i][0])); //add label to the panel
}
}

panel.add(btnCloseWindow, 490, 320)
app.add(panel);
ss.show(app);

};
```

Comment: `.setTitle('This is ' + TL + "'s Team Tasks for " + strStartDate);` the TL still doesn't show up as bold even when it is defined here: `ss.getRange('B3').setFontWeight('bold')` does that mean you cannot add a FontWeight into a Title? (The logger works fine just like you wrote it, thank you very much!)

Comment: Just to check I understand you well : do you expect that setting something to 'bold' in the spreadsheet's cell would make it appear bold in the UI ?

Comment: The value is already bold in the cell 'B3' but when the value is added to the Title it reverts to normal FontWeight @Serge That's why I thought you had to add the `"bold"` after you get the value from the cell.

Comment: this is normal, there is no link between the fontweight in the spreadsheet and the one in the UI. you have to use setStyleAttribute in the UI but it will apply to the whole string. If you need to get only a part of the string in bold then you should use a widget that supports HTML. UiInstance.setTitle does not support HTML, only string...

Comment: That was useful info, thank you - Sorry to trouble you with my mundane worries

Comment: ;-) no worries, I'm at work now, so a bit 'slow' in my answers ^^

Answer (score -1):

> var names = ss.getRange('B11:B').getValues();

Should be,

```
var names = ss.getRange('B11:B1').getValues();
```

How I researched,

```
var data = ss.getRange("b11:b1").getValues();

data.forEach(function(element,index,array){Logger.log(index + " " + element )});
```

Logs, "0 dog
1 cat
2 frog
3 fish
4 hamster
5 dog
6 cat
7 frog
8 fish
9 hamster
10 dog"

Comment: Yes it is, but are you saying it was the intent to start at B:12 till end of rows?

Comment: Column B will have an undefined number of entries. I will not know how many 'Agents' will be in Col B so therefore I cannot define it with a number. It will go on from B11 (up until the end of) B.